Unable to connect 2 lambdas with event bridge
I'm trying to connect 2 lambdas with event bridge. One lambda should send an event, and EB should trigger another lambda.
Here's receiving lambda yaml
functions:
  onTransactionPublished:
    handler: api/onTransactionPublished.handler
    events:
      - eventBridge:
          pattern:
            source:
              - aws.lambda.account
            detail-type:
              - transaction

and I'm sending the event from the first lambda like this:
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            AWS.config.update({ region: "us-east-1" });
            const eventbridge = new AWS.EventBridge();
            eventbridge.putEvents({
                Entries: [ {
                    Source: "aws.lambda.account",
                    DetailType: "transaction",
                    Detail: JSON.stringify({
                        transaction: {
                            ...transaction,
                            //publishedOn: Date(),
                            accountId: accountId
                        }
                    })
                }]
            }, (err, _) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(new Error(err.message, {cause: {statusCode: 500}}))
                } else {
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        });

Putting of the event succeeds, but for some reason the second lambda doesn't get triggered and I can't figure out why, everything looks fine in aws console.
Here's what gets generated:



Ignore the first, disabled rule, I tried to create a rule manually, but it didn't work as well. Anything that looks out of place? Thanks!

Apparently, the issue was that I was using reserved source name, since it's beginning with 'aws', so I just changed source to something custom, and it works!
